# Play 2.4 WebSocket throws InstantiationException when using compile-time dependency injection

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.4

WebSockets in Play 2.4 doesn't seem to work when using compile-time dependency injection. I'm using the latest version 2.4.2. Specifically, it throws the following exception upon connecting:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[InstantiationException: null]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:254) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$messageReceived$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:182) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$messageReceived$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:180) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:215) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: null
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at play.api.inject.NewInstanceInjector$.instanceOf(Injector.scala:49) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.inject.SimpleInjector$$anonfun$instanceOf$1.apply(Injector.scala:85) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.inject.SimpleInjector.instanceOf(Injector.scala:85) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.inject.SimpleInjector.instanceOf(Injector.scala:80) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:234) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.Application$$anonfun$instanceCache$1.apply(Application.scala:234) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.utils.InlineCache.fresh(InlineCache.scala:69) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.utils.InlineCache.apply(InlineCache.scala:62) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka$.system(Akka.scala:37) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    ...
```

Here's how the controller looks like:

```
class Application extends Controller {
  import play.api.Play.current
  def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>
    WebSocketActor.props(out)
  }
}

object WebSocketActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new WebSocketActor(out))
}

class WebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      out ! ("Received message: " + msg)
  }
}
```

And here's how the `ApplicationLoader` looks like:

```
class AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  override def load(context: Context): Application = new AppComponents(context).application
}

class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
  lazy val appController = new controllers.Application
  lazy val router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, appController, assets)
  lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Play 2.4.2. There's currently a [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4618) to fix it.

Until it's fixed, I worked around it by overriding the `injector` of `AppComponents` to also include `actorSystem`. So `AppComponents` becomes:

```
class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
  lazy val appController = new controllers.Application
  lazy val router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, appController, assets)
  lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)

  // temporary workaround until issue #4614 in playframework is fixed. See https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4614
  override lazy val injector = new SimpleInjector(NewInstanceInjector) + router.asInstanceOf[play.api.routing.Router] + crypto + httpConfiguration + actorSystem
}
```